# C# wpf scrollviewer not working like windows store app

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll, windows-store-apps, scrollviewer

I'm currently working on an application using WPF.
And I can't but help to notice the difference in ScrollViewer functionality compared to the Windows Store App variant.

When I'm at the edge of the screen and the edge of a ScrollViewer and I want to slide so that I'd move away from the edge. I see the windows desktop or menubar (when at the bottom of the screen).
Is there a solution to prevent this scroll behaviour from happening? It is rather annoying  (and ugly!) when your scrolling till the edge of the screen and then get bumped back and see a bit of the windows platform underneath.
This behaviour is fixed in the Windows Store App ScrollViewer..

I tried overwriting the `ScrollChanged` and checking if f.e. `horizontalOffset == 0 && horizontalChange < 0` and return if this is the case. But this check doesn't seem to work (since then it's probably already too late).
And I can't seem to find the way Windows Store Apps have fixed this.

[image]

Perhaps you guys have an idea?

---

**EDIT:** 
Reproduction for WPF projects in .NET 4.5.1

This piece of XAML re-creates my problem in WPF. However in Windows Store App the problem doesn't seem to exist.

How can I prevent this behaviour when scrolling to and/or over the edges of my application?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="None">
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" PanningMode="Both">
            <Rectangle Height="2500" Stroke="Black" Width="3500" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0,0.5">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF00FF68" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF95FF00" Offset="0.506"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
        </ScrollViewer>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Could you maybe provide a screenshot of the behaviour you describe?

Comment: @Richard updated for clarification. To the left you see the edge of my application. And it automagically spawns this horrific menubar as well. Both behaviours are unwanted and both are only happening in WPF and not Windows Store Apps.

Comment: Ah I see what you are talking about, what is the value of WindowState for your app?

Comment: @Richard WindowsState = "Maximised" -- ResizeMode = "NoResize" -- WindowStyle = "None"

Comment: @Sheridan That is not the issue here. It's not even the TaskBar that is the issue (it's not even on autohide on my OS). The ScrollViewer of WPF cause these to show when you are scrolling of your application. Look at the left side of the image. You see the edge of my application and a light blue bar (the actual edge) and to the left of that is (a part of) the windows desktop that I'm using.

Comment: @Sheridan It IS a programming problem since the regular ScrollViewer of WPF isn't acting like the ScrollViewer in Windows Store Apps. And there is no relevant code to post here since I do not know what is causing this effect and in which setting it lies, or in what I should customise to do so. This is the only way to describe this problem. I'm sorry this is no "I want feature A but I do not know method B" question. Have you never worked with ScrollViewers that cover your screen, are scrollable in every direction, and show this effect? You must have since you say you worked with WPF before.

Comment: @TotumusMaximus, I did not for one minute suggest that your question was off topic... I was merely requesting that you follow the advice in the [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page to create a simple test project that exhibits this issue. Whether you do this or not is totally up to you, but I fear that without doing this, your question will remain unanswered... I mean, could you tell me what was wrong with my car by just looking at it?

Comment: @Sheridan If Richard, the kind fellow that commented before you, can manage to understand it, why can't you? You can reveal some issues a car has just by looking at the outside (flat tire, broken mirror). This is just a similar case. It is a UI issue that any WPF programmer/designer with at least basic knowledge of design could've seen. That is if they ever used a ScrollViewer that bordered the edge of their application. But fine I'll post a reconstruction of the problem in a reproduction code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the default Windows 8 behavior related to scrolling. Your entire app will "bounce" when hitting the edge of a scroll-able view. This happens in every single cases and is part of the system animations. You can see it, for instance, in the Windows Explorer when in a long list of folders. This only happens when scrolling through touch and, if I remember correctly, on non full-screen applications. I do not currently have access to a Windows 8 machine to test this claim <strike>and there might very well be no way to disable this behavior</strike>.

The Modern environment is a completely separate application environment and does not handle touch gestures in the same way at all. This is why this behavior does not exists in a WinRT application.

**EDIT** : This effect is called the Manipulation Boundary Feedback. It triggers when a manipulation event goes beyond the limits of its container. You can disable it overriding the `OnManipulationBoundaryFeedback(ManipulationBoundaryFeedbackEventArgs)` method on the affected `UIElement` like so:

```
class NoTouchFeedbackWindow : Window
{
    protected override void OnManipulationBoundaryFeedback(ManipulationBoundaryFeedbackEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

This could also be done directly on your ScrollViewer or any control up the chain.

You can find more information about this behavior on:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988680(v=vs.110).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.onmanipulationboundaryfeedback(v=vs.110).aspx

Hopefully, this should solve your issue.

Comment: Mmm.. So you are saying this might not be solvable at all. I can confirm the same behaviour for fullscreen applications and Windows7 if that is any help reproducing. So it might be a remnant of their first solutions to touch interface problems.

Comment: I have updated the answer with more information about the behavior and how you can disable it.

Comment: This is it! And it turns out it is really easy to implement as well. How did you find out this was the thing?

Comment: I stumbled on this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg232767.aspx which used the term "boundaries and bounce back" when trying to prevent manipulated items from moving outside the window when dealing with inertia drag and drop. The answer was in the second result when googling for "manipulation boundary wpf". If it wasn't for this article, I would have never thought about looking for those keywords.

Comment: Hah, well I wouldn't have come up with that (otherwise the whole need of this post would've been useless) :D. And I can't say after trying to reproduce your search that I could backtrack to your answer easily. A very nice job you did indeed.