# WPF C# touch scroll is dragging the whole window

Tags: c#, wpf, multi-touch

I am developing a WPF application with touchscreen support and I have an issue: while scrolling a `ScrollViewer` using a touchscreen the whole application window is being dragged a little when scroll reaches `ScrollViewer` top or bottom. Is it possible to disable this behavior?

Comment: I know it's been a year, but did you solve this problem? If so, could you accept the answer that helped/create your own answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know people don't like link only answers but I had this problem and used this link to help out:

[C# wpf scrollviewer not working like windows store app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22555496/c-sharp-wpf-scrollviewer-not-working-like-windows-store-app)

The default behavior is to make your app bounce when you scroll to the top or bottom or side to side limits. Use ManipulationBoundaryFeedback event and add this to the code behind.

```
  private void OnManipulationBoundaryFeedback(object sender, ManipulationBoundaryFeedbackEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

Comment: This should be the answer, I think

Answer (score 1):

After reading throught .NET source I've figured out this:

```
public class CustomScrollViewer : ScrollViewer
{
    protected override void OnManipulationDelta(ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnManipulationDelta(e);
        e.ReportBoundaryFeedback(new ManipulationDelta(new Vector(0, 0), 0, new Vector(0, 0), new Vector(0, 0)));
    }
}
```

When user tries to scroll too far the additional delta gets reported to the operating system, an this intercepts that beahavior. Make sure that the call to base implementation is the first one. Also, if you're using controls with `ScrollViewer` in their template you can try subscribing to that event instead, but I can't guarantee that it will work. It's all a matter of who reports last.

Answer (score 0):

It might just be to handle the event before it bubbles (see MSDN  https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms742806(v=vs.100).aspx for informations about this).

Subscribe to

```
 ScrollViewer.PreviewTouchUp
```

With this

```
private void UIElement_OnPreviewTouchUp(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Subscribe to TouchMove and check if your table is at the end, if yes, set e.Handled = true (before make the table check, just test with e.Handled=true to see if scroll continues)

Comment: if (scrollViewer.VerticalOffset == 0) e.Handled = true; still does't work